# SSH tunnel for serving web sites from localhost

Tags: http, vps, ssh-tunnel, tunneling, stunnel

This is more question...

When I do like this... I am able to serve my site to external IP of my VPS...

`ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 username@server.com`

How secure and is it okay to serve websites trought ssh tunnel from my VPS? Should I do this in production?

Comment: A VPS should be able to serve to a public IP without ssh. SSH doesn't add any security value in this architecture.

Comment: But I need VPS just to forward staff from the web to the internet from my localhost... Similar like ngrock app works